# Calculator in C++ Help. Can't Return Running Total

Tags: c++

I have to make a Calculator using a constructor and destructor, that adds, subtracts, multiplies and divides, and returns the total every time. For some reason, when I call the line "Calculator.add(num);" or any of the "Calculator." portions return me an error saying that it "expected an identifier". Am I missing something simple?

Thanks.
Here is my main.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Calculator.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
double total;
int main(){
  while (true){
    cout << "*** Calculator *** " << endl;
    cout << "A: Add a value " << endl;
    cout << "S: Subtract a value " << endl;
    cout << "M: Multiply by a value " << endl;
    cout << "D: Divide by a value " << endl;
    cout << "T: Get the total " << endl;
    cout << "Q: Quit " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    char input;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == 'A'){
        cout << "Current Total: " << total << endl;
        cout << "Selection: A";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "*** Add selected *** " << endl;
        cout << "Value:";
        double num;
        cin >> num;
        cout << endl;
        double turnTotal = total;
        Calculator.add(num);
        cout << turnTotal << "+" << num << " = " << total;
    }
    if (input == 'S'){
        cout << "Current Total: " << total << endl;
        cout << "Selection: S";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "*** Subtract selected *** " << endl;
        cout << "Value: ";
        double num2;
        cin >> num2;
        cout << endl;
        double turnTotal2 = total;
        Calculator.subtract(num2);
        cout << turnTotal2 << "-" << num2 << "=" << total;
    }
    if (input == 'M'){
        cout << "Current Total: " << total << endl;
        cout << "Selection: M";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "*** Multiply selected *** " << endl;
        cout << "Value: ";
        double num3;
        cin >> num3;
        cout << endl;
        double turnTotal3 = total;
        Calculator.multiply(num3);
        cout << turnTotal3 << "*" << num3 << "=" << total;
    }

    if (input == 'D'){
        cout << "Current Total: " << total << endl;
        cout << "Selection: D";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "*** Divide selected *** " << endl;
        cout << "Value: ";
        double num4;
        cin >> num4;
        cout << endl;
        double turnTotal4 = total;
        Calculator.divide(num4);
        cout << turnTotal4 << "/" << num4 << "=" << total;
    }
    if (input == 'T'){
        cout << "Current Total: " << total << endl;
        cout << "Selection: T";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "*** Total selected *** " << endl;
        cout << "Value: ";
        double num5;
        cin >> num5;
        cout << endl;
        double turnTotal5 = total;
        Calculator.getTotal(num5);
        cout << turnTotal5 << "-" << num5 << "=" << total;
    }
    if (input == 'Q'){
        cout << "Thank you for using the calculator! Bye bye! Have a great day!" << endl;

    }
  }
}
```

And here is the .cpp file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Calculator.h"
using namespace std;
Calculator::Calculator(double x){
  double total = x;
  return;
}
double Calculator::getTotal(){
  return total;
}
void Calculator::add(double x){
  total += x;
}
void Calculator::subtract(double x){
  total -= x;
}
void Calculator::multiply(double x){
  total *= x;
}
void Calculator::divide(double x){
  total /= x;
}
```

And here's the class .h file.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//class specification
class Calculator {

  public:
    //constructor
    Calculator(){double total = 0;}
    Calculator(double total);

    //member functions
    void add(double x);
    void subtract(double x);
    void multiply(double x);
    void divide(double x);
    double getTotal();

    //destructor
    ~Calculator();

  private:
    //data
    double total = 0;
};
```

Comment: `Calculator` is a class definition, you need to instantiate an instance of it to be able to use it.

Comment: maybe you should learn about classes first - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: `double total = x;` That will not do what you want! Hint: total is a local variable to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You doesn't seem to initialize your *Calculator* first. You could add the initialization for example on the start of *main* function as follows

```
double total;
Calculator calc;
int main(){
  while (true){
```

And then use it like

```
calc.add(num);
```

Comment: Thanks @JonathanPotter for your edit, it seems my C++ skills are a little rusty after doing so much JavaScript... :)